# Can $Z$ be a function of $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

The three random variables $X,Y$ and  $Z$ are pairwise independent. Can $Z$ be a function of $X$ and $Y$, and by this I mean $Z=f(X,Y)$, where $f$ is a function?

Comment: If $Z$ was a function of $X$ and $Y$, wouldn't it not be independent of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: It is independent of $X$ and $Y$, but what about $X,Y$?

Comment: $f(X,Y)$ is (in general) *not* independent of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yes you are right, but you said  IN GENERAL. Is there any case, which $f(X,Y)$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I think so, yes. There's a trivial example I can think of: We can consider any function $Z$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$—even if no $X$ or $Y$ are present in the calculation of $Z$. (Think: $f(x) = 5$. There's no $x$, but we can still consider it a function of $x$.)

Comment: Forget my last comment! I'd put this as an answer, but I don't understand it well enough to: It's on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence)

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Sorry, Ii edited the question. I confused pairwise with mutual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
Consider the following example.
$X$ and $Y$ are independent Bernoulli($1/2$) random variables,
and let $Z = f(X,Y) = X \oplus Y$, where $\oplus$ denote the exclusive-or operation.

$X$ and $Y$ are pairwise independent by construction.
$Z$ is pairwise independent of $X$ (due to the presence of $Y$),
and similarly pairwise independent of $Y$ (due to the presence of $Y$).
You should compute the pairwise probability distributions to verify that.